# Workaround for Your Flash settings will be kept until you quit Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, flash

For some time now, websites are being dissuaded from offering flash content. A while ago google took it to the next level, and [now you have to enable flash manually every single time](https://www.wired.co.uk/article/google-chrome-adobe-flash-html5).

Though I appreciate the effort on a global level, and know some the obvious workarounds:

- use a different browser
- never close the browser
- click enable every time you have closed the browser
- tell the website to get rid of flash content

I just really want to use flash in the current version of chrome without the constant reminder that google is purposely making my life slightly less convenient in the short term.

Hence my question:

## How to make sure that chrome does not need a manual click each time to enable flash

Ideally the solution would just allow me to open flash up for the domain of my choice with minimal effort.

If the solution might stop working after an upgrade, is slightly more complex than justified by the problem, or is not recommended because it involves some risk (e.g. chance to mess up my operating system) that is acceptable. Warnings are appreciated though!

---

The most recent solution I found was disabling ephemeral flash permissions, but that is no longer available via the settings.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I found the documentation for this setting so the below steps can be applied to any OS: According to https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#PluginsAllowedForUrls - you can add sites you want to automatically run flash on with this list. This includes * - but please don't do that -  seriously, see end of this answer.

Detailed Windows Steps:

**WARNING**: *mistakes in your registry could prevent your computer from booting or working correctly - use at your own risk.*

You can add sites to your registry for Chrome Policies "PluginsAllowedForUrls" - this is not specific to Flash, but is currently the only setting I see impacted by the change when viewing: chrome://settings/content/siteDetails?site=https%3A%2F%2Fmytrustedsite.com

Using regedit, navigate to the below key & create new String Values for each site you want to permanently allow Flash to run on (http:// could be used too if you just throw all caution to the wind):

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\PluginsAllowedForUrls]
New String Values can be added here for trusted sites:
  "1" = "https://my.trustedsite.com"   <-- specific site format
  "2" = "https://[*.]trustedsite.com"  <-- if you want to trust all sub-domains too
  "3" = "https://*" <-- please don't do this. seriously, don't do this.
```

Note: If "Google\Chrome\PluginsAllowedForUrls" Keys (folders) do not already exist, create them, then create the String Values.

Restart Chrome & open your trusted site - Flash should now load & site settings will reflect "Flash allowed by your administrator"

[Flash allowed by your administrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isqGu.png)

**Extra word of caution about enabling this with 'http://* or https://*'** - PLEASE DON'T DO THIS.

See any # of articles on the security risks of flash, which may stop getting any security patches by Adobe as early 2020. [here is a recent USA Today article](https://www.usatoday.com/story/tech/columnist/2018/09/24/googles-latest-chrome-update-tightens-locks-adobe-flash/1348935002/)

Comment: Did not have a chance to try this, but wonder why it is down voted?! Hopefully not mere risk aversion.

Comment: my first answer ever, and I also was surprised by the down vote - please report back if this works for you!

Comment: This is excellent. I have no idea why it was downvoted, but I might add that it wasn't obvious that the string values should be added with 1, 2, 3, etc as names, and putting the site URL as value. I tried adding with the URL as name first, which had no effect. I would also put emphasis on that you most likely will need to add these keys, there is no "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Google" from a default install.